# Как передать в функцию в хуке данные?

Tags: wordpress

Есть хук:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'setDataInterval');
```

и есть функция

```
function setDataInterval($endDate){
        $where = '';
        $from =  $endDate; // промежуток времени c 15.11 до 24.12
        $to = date("Y-m-d");
//         $to = "2020-11-01";
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '$from' AND post_date <= '$to'";
     return $where;
    }
```

В которую надо передать результат работы другой функции, а она в свою очередь получает результат работы третьей функции.
Как мне в хуке вызвать функцию с параметром? или передать ей этот параметр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в функции setDataInterval

В параметре передается $where, а не значение даты.

Примерный код

```
function setDataInterval($where){

        $from =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));

        $to = date("Y-m-d");

        $where .= " AND post_date >= '$from' AND post_date <= '$to'";

        return $where;
}
```